# In Backbone, why is my collection.create() returning 'Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function'?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to learn Backbone but can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong here. My `App.wishlists.create(data);` line is returning `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`. Any help would be really appreciated!

```
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* src/models/wishlist.js
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
(function($, App, Wishlist) {

  Wishlist.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      title: ''
    }
  });

  App.wishlist = new Wishlist.Model;

}(jQuery, WL.module('app'), WL.module('wishlist')));

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* src/collections/wishlists.js
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
(function($, App, Wishlist) {

  Wishlist.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: App.wishlist,

    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('wishlists-backbone')

  });

  App.wishlists = new Wishlist.Collection;

}(jQuery, WL.module('app'), WL.module('wishlist')));


/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* src/views/wishlist/edit.js
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
(function($, App, Wishlist) {

  Wishlist.Views.Edit = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#main',

    events: {
      'submit form': 'save'
    },

    template: _.template($('#wishlist-edit-template').html()),

    render: function() {
      this.$el.html(this.template());
    },

    save: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = $(e.target).serializeObject();
      App.wishlists.create(data);
      //e.preventDefault();
    }

  });

  App.wishlistEditView = new Wishlist.Views.Edit;

}(jQuery, WL.module('app'), WL.module('wishlist')));

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* src/app.js
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
var WL = WL || {};

WL.module = _.memoize(function(module) {
  return { Views: {} };
});

(function($, App) {
  var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      '':          'home',
      'new':       'edit',
      'edit/:id':  'edit'
    }
  });

  // on DOM ready
  $(function() {
    App.router = new Router;

    App.router.home = function(params) {
      new App.Views.Main;
    };

    App.router.edit = function(params) {
      App.wishlistEditView.render();
    };

    App.router.on('route', function(route, params) {
      App.router[route](params);
    });

    Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });
  });

}(jQuery, WL.module('app')));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
model: App.wishlist
```

You're setting the collection's `model` property to an instance of the wishlist model instead of the class. Do this instead:

```
model: WishList
```

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. It needed to be Wishlist.Model. Thank you :)